# my htaccess rule is not firing for some reason?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

Running into an issue with my isapi rewrite 3 running on windows ... for some reason it is not picking up the following URL and cant figure out why...

url: (http://www.domain.com/asdf/xyz)

htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/asdf\/xyz?$ http://domain.com/apples [L,QSA,R=301]
```

what am i missing here? I have the "?" just incase someone puts the trailing slash...

Thanks

Citti

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule should not start with a `/` or it won't be matched. Apache strips of the prepending slash in .htaccess. Also in order to make the trailing slash optional you need to have the slash there including the `?`

```
RewriteRule ^asdf/xyz/?$ http://domain.com/apples [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Note: I did mention Apache even though it appears you're using IIS with a .htaccess module. It still should work the same way if it's compatible.

Comment: hmmm. was able to get this to ping back true while testing :http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ 
but my live server will not recognize this.  and i have tested to make sure the rewrite module is working by just redirecting the domain at the top level.  any thoughts?

Comment: That is just a tester. It's not absolute and it doesn't always work for every situation. You need to use that only for basic stuff. It's in the documentation. **In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule